# How to show default local time zone of Philippines?

Tags: php, timezone

How can I show the local date and time for Philippines?

```
<? php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    echo "<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>Date: </span>". date('F j, Y g:i:a  ');
?>
```

Comment: Time zone offset: UTC + 8 hours

Comment: remove the space between your php tag

`<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
echo "<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>Date: </span>". date('F j, Y g:i:a  ');
?>`

Comment: it gives me 8hours advance... -_-

Answer (score 11):

You shouldn't add space between `<?` and `php`

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
echo "<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>Date: </span>". date('F j, Y g:i:a  ');
?>
```

Comment: i did that, but i want to set the local time... that code give

Date: September 19, 2014 4:59:am

i want Date: September 18, 2014 2:00pm

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code except what this answer suggests. See here https://eval.in/194864

Comment: @TuperEvangelista `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');` has already set your timezone correctly

Comment: I'm in China, I have the same timezone with you. Your code works fine on my computer, that's 2pm. Couldn't be sth else change your time setting?

Answer (score 1):

As @worldask already sad you shouldn't add space between those `<? php` . The rest of the code is good. 
The reason why you don't get the date you want, is that the server's time is different than you think it is. When the PHP engine adds 8 hours to his **system date** it gives you a good result. In order to check which is the current hour and debug your problem use the following code, then fix the system's date.

```
<?php
echo "Current timezone: ".date_default_timezone_get()."</ br>
      Current time: ".date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
?>
```

Comment: For sure there isn't something wrong with your code.

Comment: it gives me 8hours advance -_-

Comment: @TuperEvangelista then the problem is with your system date. If you develop on your local machine and it has the correct date, then the problem stays in your php.ini file. Please set it up correctly. If you develop on a server adjust the date and time to your needs.